# Add text shadow/outline to text labels in R plotly

Tags: r, plotly

I'd like to see if I can add a black outline to white text in a `plotly` chart in `R`.

I found the following link describing how it could be done in `plotly.js` but not sure it can be done in `R` as of yet. https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/1597

Here's a sample chart.

```
library(plotly)

plot_ly(x = c('Product A', 'Product B', 'Product C'), 
        y = c(20, 14, 23), 
        type = 'bar', 
        marker = list(color = 'rgb(158,202,225)',
                           line = list(color = 'rgb(8,48,107)', width = 1.5))) %>%
  add_annotations(text = c(20, 14, 23),
                  x = c('Product A', 'Product B', 'Product C'),
                  y = c(20, 14, 23)/2,
                  xref = "x",
                  yref = "y",
                  font = list(family = 'Arial',
                              size = 14,
                              color = 'rgb(245, 246, 249)'),
                  showarrow = FALSE)
```

[image: Sample Plot]

Comment: Just to make sure; You're not talking about the background right? But rather a black outline of each and every letter?

Comment: @vestland Right, an outline around each letter.

Comment: I added another possible approach. It's not perfect, but hopefully something you could use until a better approach is implemented

Comment: How did my suggestion work out for you?

Comment: @vestland Hey. I tried your first suggestion but it didn't quite look right. It was a nice attempt though. I ended up just defining the color scale to use in my real chart to increase the contrast between the background and white text. Hopefully, `plotly` will add this functionality in `R` at some point.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there's no direct way to include an outline on each and every letter. But I was able to hack something together that *might* be of interest to you. The following code snippet uses two annotation layers where the bottom layer uses a dark and bold font, and the upper layer is slightly skewed by inserting an empty space in the text to be displayed. This gives an effect that looks pretty much like a shadow.

**Plot:**

[image]

**Code**

```
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)

p <- plot_ly(x = c('Product A', 'Product B', 'Product C'), 
        y = c(20, 14, 23), 
        type = 'bar', 
        marker = list(color = 'rgb(158,202,225)',
                           line = list(color = 'rgb(8,48,107)', width = 1.5))) %>%
  add_annotations(text = c('<b>20</b>', '<b>14</b>', '<b>23</b>'),
                  x = c('Product A', 'Product B', 'Product C'),
                  y = c(20, 14, 23)/2,
                  xref = "x",
                  yref = "y",
                  align='left',
                  font = list(family = 'Times New Roman',
                              size = 24,
                              color = 'black'),

                  showarrow = FALSE) %>%

  add_annotations(text = c('20 ', '14 ', '23 '),
                  x = c('Product A', 'Product B', 'Product C'),
                  y = c(20, 14, 23)/2,
                  xref = "x",
                  yref = "y",
                  #align="right",
                  font = list(family = 'Times New Roman',
                              size = 24,
                              color = 'white'),
                  #bgcolor="black",
                  showarrow = FALSE)


p
```

As you can see, these adjustments have mostly been hard-coded and could be made more flexible if this is something you could use. And mayb you can find a combination of bold / not bold and a font type that actually looks good?

The second best approach (or even the best) could be to just include `bgcolor="black"` in `add_annotations()` to get this:

**Plot:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)

p <- plot_ly(x = c('Product A', 'Product B', 'Product C'), 
        y = c(20, 14, 23), 
        type = 'bar', 
        marker = list(color = 'rgb(158,202,225)',
                           line = list(color = 'rgb(8,48,107)', width = 1.5))) %>%
  add_annotations(text = c(20, 14, 23),
                  x = c('Product A', 'Product B', 'Product C'),
                  y = c(20, 14, 23)/2,
                  xref = "x",
                  yref = "y",
                  font = list(family = 'Arial',
                              size = 14,
                              color = 'rgb(245, 246, 249)'),
                  bgcolor="black",
                  showarrow = FALSE)


p
```